# Filter out certain rows if one row contains certain data

Tags: sql

I am trying to figure out how to get a query to come back with certain rows if other rows contain certain data.

| SKU | Bin |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | A1 |
| 1234 | NoBin |
| 4567 | NoBin |
| 8997 | Conveyor |
| 6543 | MLSTAGE |
| 2101 | A2 |
| 2101 | Conveyor |

This is a very simple version but I only want to see SKUs 4567, 8997, and 6543 come back because 1234 and 2101 are located in Bin A1 and A2. I only want to see items that are ONLY in NoBin, MLSTAGE, or Conveyor.

I can't figure out how to get it and of course there are millions of SKUs.

Any help would be great. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
select SKU
from T
group by SKU
having count(case when Bin not in ('NoBin', 'MLSTAGE', 'Conveyor') then 1 end) = 0
```

or equivalent (if there are nulls):

```
having count(case when Bin in ('NoBin', 'MLSTAGE', 'Conveyor') then 1 end) = count(*)
```

Answer (score 0):

You essentially want to check for existence, so `EXISTS` seems a logical choice:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    YourTable T
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
                       SELECT NULL
                       FROM   YourTable T2
                       WHERE  T2.Bin NOT IN ('NoBin', 'MLSTAGE', 'Conveyor')
                          AND T2.SKU = T.SKU
                   )
    AND T.Bin IN ('NoBin', 'MLSTAGE', 'Conveyor')
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a not exists

```
select * from mytable a
 where not exists (
   select 1 from mytable b
   where a.sku = b.sku and b.bin not in
   ('NoBin', 'MLSTAGE', 'Conveyor'))
```

here is the fiddle   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5c370c7766acfbb9552bbbd32cf5e03a

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
SKU 
FROM [SKU TEST]
WHERE SKU NOT IN 
(
SELECT SKU
FROM [SKU TEST]
WHERE BIN NOT IN ('NoBin', 'Conveyor', 'MLSTAGE')
)
```

Inner query is used to build a set of SKU that are associated with everything you don't want, so not in your 3 criteria.  The outer query is generating a list of SKU's that are not in your inner set which should give you want you want.  I went with basic script to ensure it would work with pretty much any RDBMS.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Thanks for the insights, I just started back up using this platform.  @JeremyCaney